# How to check javascript object null or not?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON like this in which every keys have some value but prescription in just another object within the object so if a prescription is an empty object so how can I check whether Prescription is null or not?

```
var obj={  
   "index":"1",
   "Product_Id":"124",
   "Name":"Vincent 1",
   "Unit_Price":"1",
   "Base_Price":5,
   "Gross_Price":200,
   "Quantity":200,
   "Net_Price":200,
   "Tax":200,
   "Tax_Rate":200,
   "prescription":{  

   }
}
```

Comment: You mean like `if (object.prescription == null)` ?

Comment: As you said, prescription is an empty object, NOT `null`

Comment: In case if you want to check for empty or not, you can do it by : `Object.entries(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object` and if you want to check for null/undefined then you can just do `if (object.prescription) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

If your object name is `obj`, this will give the result you want.

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.prescription).length > 0`

Comment: object.prescription isn't null. It's empty. Empty and Null are NOT the same thing. Your check will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `Object.keys(obj.prescription).length`, to check if the object contains any keys.
Of course this for empty obect, as in your example, not null

Comment: You should always additionally check for obj.constructor === Object since if you did something like obj.prescription(new Date()).length would still === 0.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking doesn't make any sense because prescription isn't null and never will be in this example. It is simply an empty object.  An empty object and null are NOT the same thing.

You also don't want to simply check for length === 0 because this can return as false at times when it is actually true...

```
Object.keys(obj.prescription).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object;
```

will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How is the json object being used? I mean what are you using to parse json object? For example in javascript following code can be used:

```
function isEmpty(object) {
    for(var key in object) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```